# Key binding wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am using the following tag in my `xaml` to bind the enter key to a command.

```
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding EnterKeyCommand}" Key="Enter" />
```

But if i press the enter key 5 times (very quickly) the command is called 5 times. How can i prevent this?

Comment: That would be the expected behaviour.  What do you want to happen?  Do you want the command to only ever run once; or for there to be a delay before it can be ran again?

Comment: This is generally called "debouncing".  There are many ways to accomplish it.  I think the cleanest is using the Reactive Extensions, which makes it easy to throttle events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `EnterKeyCommand` is an `ICommand`, set its `ICommand.CanExecute` to `false` when it is invoked, and back to `true` when it is ok to execute it again (raising `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` both times).

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to add a delay between the Command executing for a first time and it being able to be executed again, you can just set canExecute to false for a period of time:

```
public class EnterKeyCommand : ICommand
{
    private bool canExecute;

    public EnterKeyCommand()
    {
        this.canExecute = true;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.canExecute = false;
        Debug.WriteLine("Running Command");

        var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };
        timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
            {
                this.canExecute = true;
                timer.Stop();
            };
        timer.Start();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```